# WCF и виртуализация: как сделать так, чтобы не вис отладчик?

Tags: отладка, visual-studio, wcf

У нас довольно много объектов, у которых ToSrting() или значения некоторых свойств при вычислении обращаются к wcf-сервису. В боевом режиме это работает нормально, но при попытке отладить клиентский код начинаются проблемы.

Как только отладчик заходит в то место, где есть такой код (на клиенте), он где-то минуту висит, потом выдаёт сообщение "Попытка выполнения управляемого кода под блокировкой OS Loader". Отключение этого предупреждения в Managed Debugging Assistants проблему не решает: отладчик минуту висит, потом отлаживаемый клиент молча вырубается.

Я видел, как у одного коллеги отладчик на этом не вис, а только выдавал, что невозможно вычислить значение свойства. Но он не знал, чем его настройки Студии отличаются от наших, мало того, теперь он уволился, а его ноутбук отдали заказчику.

Comment: Если метод ToString или свойства объекта обращаются к внешнему сервису, то это называется плохой дизайн системы. Лучше так не делать, тогда и проблем таких не будет.

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос. Я предвидел такую реакцию. Ленивая загрузка - это плохой дизайн системы?

Comment: К тому же используемые нами графические компоненты работают со свойствами и `ToString`'ами, так что особо не разбежишься.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что проблема решается так: когда отлаживаешь что-то на клиенте, сервер запускать надо без отладчика.

Ещё в Студии есть настройка, отключающая автоматическое вычисление свойств / ToString'ов отладчиком (Debugging / Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls).

Answer (score 0):

Это нарушение srp, [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)): объект является моделью для ui и отвечает за загрузку данных из внешнего источника. Если я правильно понял, как у вас это устроено. Проблемы с отладчиком - это только симптом. Я бы посоветовал объекты, на которые биндятся ui-шные компоненты, сделать максимально простыми, а загрузку и кэширование объектов с сервиса вынести в отдельный компонент.

Comment: Да, нарушение. Но принципы построения архитектуры приложений следует применять разумно. Мы, конечно же, знаем о принципе единственной ответственности и следуем ему в тех случаях, когда он не идёт вразрез с удобством работы. Если концепция системы в целом такова, что интерфейс по умолчанию автоматически генерируется по объектной модели, и это оправдано скоростью разработки типового функционала, то даже виснущий отладчик не является причиной отказываться от выбранного архитектурного решения. Пока что для обхода указанной проблемы мы пишем тесты, в которых сервисы инстанцируются локально.